# How to Write back to same Json file use for reading

Tags: c#, json, ajax

I have a JSON file That I am Use for reading and from that, I get some JSON value in order to create an ajax request and from that, ajax request I get back the that ajax content as string and write it on the new text file then I add the file name into the the object that object represents the children object of the reading JSON . I can add the value into Jason but the problem is when I tried to override those specific children it does not support I can only write them end of the page but I need to write them in specific children.

here is my treejson

here is my code

```
       private Task LoadJson(BaseDocument baseDocument)
    {
        string path = string.Empty;
        path = baseDocument.Path.ToString();
        string fulltreepath = path + "\\tree.json";

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fulltreepath))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
            dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            data = (JArray)parsed["children"][1]["children"];
        }

        foreach (JObject children in data)
        {
            var value = children.GetValue("html").ToString();
            List<string> elements = new List<string>();
            var matches = reg.Matches(value);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var theData = match.Groups[1].Value;
                elements.Add(theData);
            }
            var ParameterObject = new List<object>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                ParameterObject.Add(Int32.Parse(elements[i]));
            }
            ParameterObject.Add(elements[0]);
            var client = new RestClient("https://www.nfa.futures.org/api/DataHandlerEnforcementReg.ashx");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "111");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            request.AddHeader("Host", "www.nfa.futures.org");
            request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "c4e54cce-4d2a-4d48-a003-3e8afb205bae,9761dd14-13b5-4da1-929c-8049099b4ba7");
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"id\":1,\"method\":\"getRuleOrRules\",\"params\":{ \"sectionSeqId\" :" + ParameterObject[0] + ", \"subSectionSeqId\" :" + ParameterObject[1] + ", \"ruleId\" : \"" + ParameterObject[2] + "\"}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var res = response.Content;
            var FinalResponse = JObject.Parse(res);

            var Uri = children.GetValue("uri").ToString();

            var FileName = MD5Hash(Uri) + "_transform2";

            children.Add(new JProperty("transformedUri", FileName));

            var l = children;

            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fulltreepath, FileMode.Append))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(jw, children);
            }
            var Pathfile = path + "\\" + FileName;
            if (FinalResponse["result"]["result"][0]["RULE_DESCRIPTION"] != null)
            {
                var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FinalResponse["result"]["result"][0]["RULE_DESCRIPTION"]);
                File.WriteAllText(Pathfile, jsonData.Replace('"', ' ').Trim());
            }

        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

here is my JSON file that I used to read and write.

```
            {
         "uri": "https://www.nfa.futures.org/news/
       EnforceRegActionsSimple.aspx",
      "children": [
           {
     "uri":
          "https://www.nfa.futures.org/news/
        EnforceRegActionsSimple.aspx#145View%209%2Be12 
         33a13%401",
  "children": [
    {
           "uri": "https://www.nfa.futures.org/news/
             EnforceRegActionsSimple.aspx#1
              14Rule4%2Be6ea03f2%400%40145View%209%2Be1233a13%401",
      "cachedUri": null,
      "title": "Compliance Rules : Rule 2-2 : Rule",
      "type": "Enforcement and Registration Actions : Rule",
      "html": "<span data-rule-id=\"RULE 2-2\" data-rule-section=\"4\" data-rule-sub-section=\"0\" class=\"btn-add-rule\" data-cube-level=\"2\" data-cube-scope=\"25178371\">Rule</span>"
    },
    {
      "uri": "https://www.nfa.futures.org/news
       /EnforceRegActionsSimple.aspx#
          114Rule4%2Be6ea03f2%401%40145View%209%2Be1233a13%401",
      "cachedUri": null,
      "title": "Compliance Rules : Rule 2-4 : Rule",
      "type": "Enforcement and Registration Actions : Rule",
      "html": "<span data-rule-id=\"RULE 2-4\" data-rule-section=\"4\" data- 
      rule-sub-section=\"0\" class=\"btn-add-rule\" data-cube-level=\"2\" 
       data-cube-scope=\"59284911\">Rule</span>"
     }]
    }
     }
```

Comment: You've found the reason databases were created. With a lot of careful programming, you can read and write to the same file. But what do you do if you want to replace a 100 byte chunk of your original file with an updated chunk that's 150 bytes long. Take a look at MongoDB or one of the other JSON-friendly databases

Comment: Your JSON is not well-formed.  If I upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ I get multiple errors because 1) There are newline characters inside string values, which is not allowed; 2) The outermost `"children" : [` array lacks a closing `]` brace.  Can you please [edit] your question to include well-formed, well-formatted JSON that we can test and use a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem?  My best guess as to what well-formed JSON might look like is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/6Qrwe0gP

Comment: But as @Flydog57 mentioned above, a JSON file is not a database -- it is a text file.  You will need to deserialize the file into an in-memory data model (possibly just a `JToken` hierarchy), modify that data model, and then re-serialize to disk overwriting the previous file.

Comment: The easiest and safest way to "_re-serialize to disk overwriting the previous file_" is to serialize it out to a new file. Once it is done and closed, erase the old file and rename the new one with the old file's name.

Comment: @Flydog57 Can you show me the way to do that as an answer I did not get How to overwrite using Re-serialize